# Qt: Attempt to add Drag and Drop to Editable Tree Model example not working

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractitemview

I'm trying to learn how to implement Drag and Drop to model/view settings in Qt. As an exercise, I attempted to do that to the [Editable Tree Model example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html) available at the Qt web site:

[image: Editable Tree Model]

To extend it with Drag and Drop, I followed the instructions in Qt's documentation on ["Using Drag and Drop with View Items"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views), more specifically ["Using model/view classes"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-model-view-classes).

I placed the code for my attempt at [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/editabletreemodelwithdraganddrop). The main modifications are below but there are other important ones; [here are the full changes](https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/editabletreemodelwithdraganddrop/commit/7ccaa8511ed95267499a3e8852a3450d41a06b53) according to the documentation.

```
/* mainwindow.cpp -- THIS IS NOT ALL CHANGES -- See link above for all changes */
view->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
view->setDragEnabled(true);
view->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
view->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
view->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
```

However, this didn't quite work. While I can drag and drop items, the copied item appears as blank. This can be seen in [this screen capture](https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/editabletreemodelwithdraganddrop/blob/master/Editable%20Tree%20Model%20with%20Drag%20and%20Drop%20problem.mp4?raw=true), but the main screenshots are:

[image: Dragging "Getting Started" on "Composing the Dialog"]

[image: Results in a blank item]

Note that the documentation describes the need to re-implement `QAbstractItemModel`'s `dropMimeData` for drag and drop functionality, which I did not. This is because, upon inspecting the [source code for that class](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/52077d4f0193a236eacac98f75994b44a4c30a91/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp), I find that [its default implementation](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/52077d4f0193a236eacac98f75994b44a4c30a91/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2231) should already work in copying items in drag and drop, since it [uses the default](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/52077d4f0193a236eacac98f75994b44a4c30a91/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2231) `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist` MIME format and [uses `setItemData`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/52077d4f0193a236eacac98f75994b44a4c30a91/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2859) for the inserted items.

What is wrong here? Is it the default `dropMimeData` that's not working, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model provided by the example only accepts setting data with role `Qt::EditRole`. See line 263 in `treemodel.cpp`

```
bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role != Qt::EditRole)
        return false;

    ...
}
```

Removing that part or adding `Qt::DisplayRole` and the data will be set properly.

Comment: Terrific! Thank you!